# Strange behaviour of GetQueuedCompletionStatus when used from thread pool worker threads

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, threadpool

I've been testing to combine the IO Completion Ports with the worker threads from the Thread Pool and stumbled on a behaviour I can't explain. In particular, while the following code:

```
  int data;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
      PostQueuedCompletionStatus(cp, 1, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPOVERLAPPED>(&data));

  {
      std::thread t([&] ()
      {
            LPOVERLAPPED aux;
            DWORD        cmd;
            ULONG_PTR    key;

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
            {
              if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatus(cp, &cmd, &key, &aux, 0))
                break;
              ++count;
            }
      });

      t.join();
   }
```

works perfectly fine and receives NUM status notifications (with NUM being large number, 100000 or more), the similar code that uses the thread pool work object that reads one status notification per work item and repost the work item after reading it, fails after reading couple of hundred status notifications. Having the following global variables (please don't mind the names):

```
HANDLE cport;
PTP_POOL pool;
TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON env;
PTP_WORK work;
std::size_t num_calls;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv; 
bool job_done;
```

and the callback function:

```
static VOID CALLBACK callback(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE instance_, PVOID pv_, PTP_WORK work_)
{
  LPOVERLAPPED aux;
  DWORD        cmd;
  ULONG_PTR    key;

  if (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(cport, &cmd, &key, &aux, 0))
  {
    ++num_calls;
    SubmitThreadpoolWork(work);
  }
  else
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mutex);
    std::cout << "No work after " << num_calls << " calls.\n";
    job_done = true;
    cv.notify_one();
  }
}
```

the following code:

```
{
  job_done = false;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mutex);

  num_calls = 0;
  cport = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 1);

  pool = CreateThreadpool(nullptr);
  InitializeThreadpoolEnvironment(&env);
  SetThreadpoolCallbackPool(&env, pool);

  work = CreateThreadpoolWork(callback, nullptr, &env);

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
      PostQueuedCompletionStatus(cport, 1, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPOVERLAPPED>(&data));

  SubmitThreadpoolWork(work);
  cv.wait_for(l, std::chrono::milliseconds(10000), [] { return job_done; } );
}
```

would report "No more work after ..." after 250 or so calls to GetQueuedCompletionStatus although the NUM was set to 1000000. Even more curious is that setting the wait from 0 to, way, 10 milliseconds would increase the number of successful calls to couple of hundred thousand and would occasionally read all 1000000 notifications. Which I don't really understand since all status notifications were posted before submitting the work object for the first time.

Is it possible that there really is a problem with combining completion ports and a thread pool or is there something wrong in my code? Please don't go into why would I want to do this - I was investigating the possibilities and stumbled on this. In my view it should work and can't figure put what's wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You should inspect the value returned by `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` (and other winapi functions) and check `GetLastError` if it fails.

Comment: The full code did that, I removed checks for the sake of simplicity. No errors were reported.

Comment: You should add them back then.

Comment: They will clutter the example. This example reports incorrect (insufficient) number of status notification returned by GetQueuedCompletionStatus regardless of the error checks. In particular, when GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns false it sets the error code to 0x102 which indicates timeout which in turn indicates that there is nothing to return. No other function reports failure.

Comment: The call to `SubmitThreadpoolWork` inside of `callback` seems to be suspicions. Wouldn't this lead to invocation of the same `callback` function in another pool thread causing a race condition when trying to modify `num_calls`?

Comment: It shouldn't. Work is resubmitted after increment. In any case, in one of the attempts I've made `num_calls` to be `std::atomic` to no avail. You have a point, though, resubmitting the work item from the `callback` that is the same work item ... but I found nothing that would say it can't be done. MSDN only states that the same work item can be resubmitted more than once at any time.

Comment: But have you tried removing resubmission?

Comment: Well, then it would fetch only one status notification, which is not what I want. My idea was to use I/O completion port as a sort of multi-producer/single consumer fifo queue in front of the thread pool to control the execution sequence ... to get the execution serialization, which is something the thread pool (unlike Apple's GCD) doesn't do. Anyway, there are other possibilities for fifo, I'm not too unhappy about this, I'm just wondering why this isn't working when, as I understand it, should.

Comment: What I haven't tried, though, is resubmission on itself, w/o completion port. Just changed the condition in the `callback` to `if (num_calls < 1000000)` and it works like a charm - hence resubmission isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried running this code, the issue seems to be the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` parameters supplied to `CreateIoCompletionPort`. Passing 1 means that the first pool thread that executes `callback` becomes associated with io completion port but since thread pool may execute `callback` using different thread `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` will fail when this happens. [From documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The most important property of an I/O completion port to consider carefully is the concurrency value. The concurrency value of a completion port is specified when it is created with `CreateIoCompletionPort` via the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` parameter. This value limits the number of runnable threads associated with the completion port. When the total number of runnable threads associated with the completion port reaches the concurrency value, the system blocks the execution of any subsequent threads associated with that completion port until the number of runnable threads drops below the concurrency value.
>
> Although any number of threads can call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` for a specified I/O completion port, when a specified thread calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` the first time, it becomes associated with the specified I/O completion port until one of three things occurs: The thread exits, specifies a different I/O completion port, or closes the I/O completion port. In other words, a single thread can be associated with, at most, one I/O completion port.

So to use io completion with thread pool you need to set the number of concurrent threads to the size of the thread pool (that you can set using `SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum`).

```
::DWORD const threads_count{1};

cport = ::CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, threads_count);
...
pool = ::CreateThreadpool(nullptr);
::SetThreadpoolThreadMaximum(pool, threads_count);
```